# Подбор части пароля перебором (brute force attack) по маске и sha-256

Tags: python, python-3.x, криптография, хеширование

У меня есть кусок пароля `*elp**` (вместо звездочек должны быть символы, которые надо подобрать), но я знаю от него `sha256` хеш:

```
fda23a72c73c92a1ad61cd18c58961b90c2c127028c8b87fd1a65c5e1f55d17e
```

Мне надо подобрать из всей этой информации к нему пароль
(если что, пароль `helpMe`)

я написала кусок программы и не знаю как сделать дальше

```
import hashlib
mas = ["A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K","L","M","N","O","P","Q","R","S","T","U","V","W","X","Y","Z","a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","0"]

a = b'Hello'
sha = hashlib.sha256(a).hexdigest()

print(sha)
```

Comment: я хочу быть скиловым программистом

Comment: тогда для начала советую организовать в самом примитивном варианте: три вложенных цикла и каждый подбирает одну букву. А дальше уже думать как свернуть это сначала в один цикл для заранее заданной строки, а потом уже и как сделать всё это для произвольной строки.

Answer (score 7):

Попробуйте так:

```
import string    
import hashlib
from itertools import product

def brute_force(mask, hsh, alphabet=string.ascii_letters+string.digits, verbose=False):
    # экранируем фигурные скобки
    # и заменяем '*' на '{}' для последующей подстановки в 'str.format()'
    pwd_pat = mask.replace('{', '{{').replace('}','}}').replace('*', '{}')
    # число звездочек - будем использовать в качестве `product(.., repeat)`
    N = mask.count('*')
    i = 0
    for chars in product(alphabet, repeat=N):
        if verbose:
            i += 1
            if i % 10000 == 0:
                print('Iterations: {}'.format(i))
        if hsh == hashlib.sha256(pwd_pat.format(*chars).encode()).hexdigest():
            return pwd_pat.format(*chars)
    return None
```

Тест:

```
hsh = 'fda23a72c73c92a1ad61cd18c58961b90c2c127028c8b87fd1a65c5e1f55d17e'

In [245]: brute_force('*elp**', hsh, verbose=True)
Iterations: 10000
Iterations: 20000
Out[245]: 'helpMe'
```

Comment: Так просто, взял на заметку.

Comment: это сломается, если mask уже содержит `{}`.

Comment: @jfs, это легко решается: `mask.replace('{', '{{').replace('}','}}')...`

Comment: @MaxU конечно, любой баг можно исправить. Только не в комментарии, а код в ответе поправить следует.

Answer (score 3):

Вариант, который работает с байтами и использует все доступные CPU:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import hashlib
import itertools
import multiprocessing
import string
from functools import partial

alphabet = string.ascii_lowercase.encode()


def sha256(data):
    return hashlib.sha256(data).digest()


def check_sha256(repls_parent, bytes_format, n, target_sha256):
    for repls in itertools.product(alphabet, repeat=n):
        data = bytes_format % (repls_parent + repls)
        if sha256(data) == target_sha256:
            return data


def brute_force(mask, target_sha256, n_cutoff=4):
    """
    n_cutoff -- number of `*` to process in a worker process
    """
    bytes_format = mask.replace(b'%', b'%%').replace(b'*', b'%c')
    mp_check = partial(check_sha256,
                       bytes_format=bytes_format,
                       n=min(n_cutoff, mask.count(b'*')),
                       target_sha256=target_sha256)
    n = max(0, mask.count(b'*') - n_cutoff)
    all_repls_parent = itertools.product(alphabet, repeat=n)
    with multiprocessing.Pool() as pool:
        for data in pool.imap_unordered(mp_check, all_repls_parent):
            if data is not None:
                return data
```

Пример:

```
import binascii

sha256_hex = b'c4bbcb1fbec99d65bf59d85c8cb62ee2db963f0fe106f483d9afa73bd4e39a8a'
passw_bytes = brute_force(b'******t horse battery staple',
                          binascii.unhexlify(sha256_hex))
print(passw_bytes.decode())
```

Задача распараллеливается, делегированием генерации `n_cutoff` замен в дочерние процессы. Задача подходит для вычисления на GPU. Из-за связи sha256 с Bitcoin mining существуют ASIC, заточенные под вычисление хэшей.

Чтобы отслеживать прогресс, можно [`tqdm` модуль](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/tqdm) использовать:

```
from tqdm import tqdm

#...
all_repls_parent = itertools.product(alphabet, repeat=n)
with multiprocessing.Pool() as pool:
    for data in tqdm(pool.imap_unordered(mp_check, all_repls_parent),
                     total=len(alphabet)**n):
        if data is not None:
            return data
```